# Ximea package for ros-melodic

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am looking for a Ximea ros package for melodic but couldnt find any. I did however find the package for ros Indigo. I want to use the camera in Ubuntu 18.04 where Indigo is not compatible. Can one one suggest a possible solution.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/362003/ximea-package-for-ros-melodic/) by [shashank.shivakumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/59830/shashank.shivakumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2020-09-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I did a cursory search. I don't see a driver for Melodic. You have a few options.

1. Fork the driver and upgrade it.
2. Ask the maintainer to upgrade it,
   possibly with your help.
3. Ask the
   vendor to release a ROS package for
   their hardware. I know I have asked
   them in the past to do this.

Given the situation option 1 is probably the best choice and probably easier than you think unless there were major changes to Ximea's API.

---

Originally posted by [kscottz](https://answers.ros.org/users/13336/kscottz/) with karma: 209 on 2020-09-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shashank.shivakumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/59830/shashank.shivakumar/) on 2020-09-23**:
Thanks for the reply. I guess option 1 is the best .

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried this package/instruction:
[ximea_ros_cam](https://github.com/wavelab/ximea_ros_cam)

It works for me with Melodic and USB3

Cheers
Robert

---

Originally posted by [RobertZickler](https://answers.ros.org/users/52301/robertzickler/) with karma: 104 on 2020-10-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shashank.shivakumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/59830/shashank.shivakumar/) on 2020-10-14**:
Yes this worked for me. Thanks